# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На сайте есть 2 ошибки. Первая заключается в том, что маска в поле телефон в форме выдает ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вторая ошибка в вызове модального окна - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую jquery-3.6.3

Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Первая ошибка сообщает, что jQuery не подключена, a вторая намекает на отсутствие точки между закрывающей круглой скобкой и on.

Answer (score 2):

Первая ошибка сообщает, что *jQuery* не подключена, a вторая намекает на отсутствие точки между закрывающей круглой скобкой и `on`.